# Intersection of separable metric spaces endowed with the sum of metrics

Tags: metric-spaces, separable-spaces

We are given two metric spaces $(\mathfrak X_1,d_1)$ and $(\mathfrak X_2,d_2)$ which we assume separable and such that $\mathfrak X:= \mathfrak X_1 \cap \mathfrak X_2 \neq \emptyset$.

Define $d(x,y):= d_1(x,y) + d_2(x,y)$ for $x,y\in\mathfrak X$.

Is $(\mathfrak X,d)$ separable?

My attempt: let $(u_n)_n$ be dense in $\mathfrak X_1$, and $(v_m)_m$ be dense in $\mathfrak X_2$. Pick rational radii $0<q\in\mathbb Q$. Then pick $y_{n,q}\in B(u_n,q;\mathfrak X_1)\cap \mathfrak X_2$ and $z_{m,q}\in B(v_m,q;\mathfrak X_2)\cap \mathfrak X_1$ , whenever these intersections are not empty. That would be the candidates for my dense set, but I cannot conclude from here.

Comment: As a member of over 3 years, you should already know this, but just in case, let me re-emphasize. Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)'s a quick guide (if nothing else, read up the part on "avoiding no-clue questions")

Comment: All right: let $(u_n)_n$ be dense in $\mathfrak X_1$, and $(v_m)_m$ be dense in $\mathfrak X_2$. Pick rational radii $0<q\in\mathbb Q$.

Then pick $y_{n,q}\in B(u_n,q;\mathfrak X_1)\cap \mathfrak X_2$ and  $z_{m,q}\in B(u_m,q;\mathfrak X_2) \cap \mathfrak X_1$, whenever these intersections are not empty. That would be the candidates for my dense set, but I cannot conclude from here.

Comment: Comments can be deleted at any time, and automatically by the system.  Can you edit your question with your update, please?

Answer (score 2):

A metric space is separable iff it is second-countable. So the assumption is that we have two metrics $d_1,d_2$ on $X$ that do not necessarily have any relation, except that the topologies $T_1,T_2$ they induce on $X$ are both second-countable. The topology $T$ induced by $d_1+d_2$ is exactly the topology generated by $T_1,T_2$, i.e, the smallest topology that contains them. A basis for $T$ is $\{U\cap V\mid U\in T_1,V\in T_2\}$. You can check that this is homeomorphic to the diagonal $D=\{(x,x)\mid x\in X\}$ in $(X,T_1)\times(X,T_2)$. Since $(X,T_1)\times(X,T_2)$ is second-countable, so is $D$, and thus $(X,T)$. Therefore $(X,T)$ is separable.